# Launch Firefox Portable on Mac with a shell script

Tags: macos, shell, usb-drive

First off, allow me to state that I detest Macs in their entirety. I have little experience with them, except programming in Objective-C.

Problem: I need to be able to launch the portable firefox installation on a flash drive, under the directory

```
[Drive root]/.assets/port/Firefox Portable.app
```

Could I get some help on:

1. Making sure the shell script will accept spaces and the period on the folder names
2. Making sure the shell script will accept spaces in the filename
3. Allowing the drive root to change, similar to a leading "/" on a windows machine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
cmd=$(ls -d /Volumes/*/.assets/port/Firefox\ Portable.app 2>/dev/null | head -1) && open "$cmd"
```

will try `ls` all Firefox on all mounted drives in the /Volumes and will launch the first one. (and do nothing, when not find any Firefox.)

Explanation:

- `ls -d` try list in directory mode (so list the directory name and not it's content)
- the backshlash in the `Firefox\ Portable` - mean escape the next char, (here the `space`)
- `2>/dev/null` - dont show errors (or you can try `2>&-` too)
- `|head -1` - show only the 1st line from a result (if here is more lines)
- and everything above assign into variable `cmd` - so if here is a command, the variable will contain a pathname
- `&& open "$cmd"` - open the application on the path stored in variable $cmd WHEN the previous command succeed (so here is a command)

Comment: Nice.  Assuming that path is unique on all your mounted volumes and you trust it and it is a properly formatted Mac app, that should do the trick.

Comment: ;) yes, youre right. For the correctness should check the .../Content/MacOS/Firefox\ Portable for the existence and with the `lipo` command for the correct architecture and open afterward.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

On OS X, `open(1)` is used to launch an app from the command line:

```
open "[/Volumes/[Drive file system name]/.assets/port/Firefox Portable.app"
```

As with any standard Unix shell, enclosing the path in quotes `" "` will protect against spaces and periods.

For a given flash drive, the volume file system name will always be the same unless you change it.  If you do not know ahead of time what the file system name will be, you would need to search the mounted volumes and guess.

To be more precise, by default OS X will attempt to mount the USB drive using the same file system at the `/Volumes/[Drive file system name]` mount point *unless* that mount point is already in use by another like-named file system, in which case a modified mount point name will be used, usually by appending something.  Or you or some program could mount it manually at some arbitrary mount point.  So, in the most general case, you would need to search.  It depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I enclosed it in quotes, and it still failed (The system cannot find /.assets/port/Firefox )

Comment: So you're saying that unlike windows, there's no way to tell it to look for the file, starting in the drive root? Because the drive will mount in different places, depending on which computer it's plugged into, right? Like the driveletters on a PC?

Comment: If there is no conflicting file system already mounted (one with the same file system volume name), by default it *should* mount at the same path on every OS X system.  So you should be able to use the same file path everywhere.  Like any Unix system using an automounter, it is hard to guarantee that in every possible situation but if these are your systems and the USB drive is under your control it should work fine.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would be having problems with the quoted file name.  Are you running this directly in an OS X terminal window shell or are you running it remotely somehow?  Another way to handle it is use `\ ` to protect spaces, so `open [...]Firefox\ Portable.app`